# NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains returning empty path?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When would NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains on iOS ever return 0 paths if I have the following:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSLog(@"paths: %d", [paths count]);

if ([paths count] > 0)
{
    // path exists and is the 1st item in the array
}
else
{
    // path doesn't exist. Under what conditions would it not exist?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

Add the "s"

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part. I was curious on when there would be 0 paths (using the correct API name)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is just defensive coding. I can't see why that exact call would ever return 0 paths, but the NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains() method might do with different params passed to it.

Also, even if the path exists, the docs say that doesn't guarantee that the actual dir exists, so ideally you'd need to do another check there too, although for NSDocumentDirectory I suspect most people, myself included, just assume it will be there - can't see why it wouldn't be..

Comment: [It just returned an empty array.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938962/index-0-beyond-bounds-for-empty-array-while-getting-to-the-documents-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not crash at there. just compiler stop at the wrong postion.