# index 0 beyond bounds for empty array while getting to the documents directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, ios6

I use the following code to get to the documents directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Why would my app be crashing with the following message?

```
*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

I can't see how my `NSArray` (immutable array) can be empty. The function is supposed to return the documents folder in an array. Any ideas?

Comment: 'I can't see how my NSArrayI (immutable array) can be empty' <-- perhaps it has no items?

Comment: Thanks for the clever answer! The question is why the array is empty. Because that function is supposed to return the documents folder in an array.

Comment: @user1542795, I think the question wasn't clear enough. People don't try to be mean here on purpose.

Comment: Are there any subdirectories in NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDocuments?

Comment: This part of code seems correct. Are you sure that this is the part where your code is crashing? If you have any other NS(Mutable)Array objects in your project you should check those parts of code, too.

Comment: @Hackmodford Yes, there is a subdirectory, should that be causing a problem?

Comment: @detunized, Thanks for the edit. You answer actually did seem like a legitimate attempt to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you sure the crash is there?

2) Not totally related but can [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515979/nssearchpathfordirectoriesindomains-returns-the-wrong-directory).

Answer (score 0):

The array returned by `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` has zero elements in it. It's empty. Exactly what the error message says.

Comment: I guess the question is *why* the array is empty. Because that function is supposed to return the documents folder in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering *why*, but since Xcode 5:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
```

If it's empty, it won't raise an exception, it will return nil. No crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSHomeDirectory()` instead... It is a nicer way to get the applications home directory.

Note: If you are after the Documents Directory then you may need to append `@"Documents/"` to the string